# How to set "Ads" setting in Google Play Console

Tags: android, google-play-console

I'm trying to publish a new app to Google Play Store, I've completed all the steps required in Google Play Console except for declaring if there are any ads in the app.

The issue is when I go to "App content -> Ads", there no options to set, as shown in the second picture.

Where are the settings?

UPDATE
This seems to happen only in firefox, on chrome the options are displayed

[image: App content - Google Play Console]

[image: Ads - App content - Google Play Console]

Comment: Issue still exists in Chrome but Safari worked!

Answer (score 3):

Please Turn of your Adblocker, I was facing same issue than I turned off my adblocker and it worked

Answer (score 0):

Turning off Ad Blocker Plus in Chrome worked for me. Thanks